# Rows length getting 0 using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to fetch the number of rows in a table for under a particular classes. But, it always returns 0. Here is my code.

[image]

My code is

```
console.log("length ="+$("#dojox_grid__View_15 > .dojoxGridScrollbox > .dojoxGridContent > .dojoxGridRow > .dojoxGridRowTable tbody tr td").length);
```

What is wrong in this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to start off by saying I do not recommend you use a selector that long. It's really messy and will be hard to maintain. However, this is not the question. You were wondering why the selector wasn't working.

```
console.log("length ="+$("#dojox_grid__View_15 > .dojoxGridScrollbox > .dojoxGridContent > .dojoxGridRow > .dojoxGridRowTable tbody tr td").length);
```

The problem with this is `.dojoxGridContent > .dojoxGridRow`

`.dojoxGridRow` is not a direct child of `.dojoxGridContent` meaning you cannot use the `>` selector to access it. Instead change the console.log to:

```
console.log("length ="+$("#dojox_grid__View_15 > .dojoxGridScrollbox > .dojoxGridContent .dojoxGridRow > .dojoxGridRowTable tbody tr td").length);
```

Removing the `>`

---

I'm not sure what the rest of your code looks like so this may be wrong. But I recommend you also use: `$("#dojox_grid__View_15 .dojoxGridCell").length;`

Comment: I'm using the selector as long because there are duplicates in the DOM. So, only by ID is unique

Comment: That's fair enough. I'd still find a better way to organise the structure to make this more minimal. Has the code worked?

Comment: Yes it worked. Since DOM is not in my hand, I have to use in that way only